# How to return an object with an array within an array

Tags: reactjs

Need to return as an object or a better way of extracting data from the following data model.

```
  const dataModel = {
       data:[
        {
         id: '1234',
         entity : [{
           id: '1',
           type: 'books'
         }]
      },
      {
        id: '1234',
        entity : [{
          id: '1',
          type: 'books'
        }]
       }
     ]
  };
```

I have tried the following code

```
const getBooksId = response.data.map(values => {
  return values.entity.find(entity => 
    entity.type === 'books'
  );
  }).filter( data => data !== undefined);
}
const getMagazineId = response.data.map(values => {
  return values.entity.find(entity => 
    entity.type === 'magazine'
 );
  }).filter( data => data !== undefined);
}
```

```
let getDataIntoObject = { bookId: getBooksId[0].id, magazineId: getMagazine[0].id }
```

The `getDataIntoObject` gives me the expected result which is the `id` of each entity but the code looks messy. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that looks a bit nicer:

```js
const responseData = [
  {
    id: '123',
    entity: [{
      id: '1',
      type: 'books'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: '456',
    entity: [{
      id: '2',
      type: 'books'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: '789',
    entity: [{
      id: '3',
      type: 'magazine'
    }]
  }
];

const entities = responseData.map(d => d.entity).flat();
const book = entities.find(e => e.type === 'books');
const magazine = entities.find(e => e.type === 'magazine');

const getDataIntoObject = {
  bookId: book && book.id,
  magazineId: magazine && magazine.id
};

console.log(getDataIntoObject);
```

...and handles a `book` or `magazine` not being found.

Comment: Thanks for help. But i wanted to return the entity > id

Comment: ah, got it.  I've updated my answer above @fvnbabalu